# Use Template Filter with static path in django

Tags: css, django

I need to use simple template variable, to version my css file.
I will update the version in my settings and it will be applied automatically to all the files. 
Here is how i am doing this.

### Template Filter

```
@register.filter
def settings_value(name):
    return getattr(settings, name, "")
```

### Template

```
{% with "APP_VERSION"|settings_value  as v %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v={{ V }}"/>
{%endwith%}
```

This actually works file. 
but currently my css path is set as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css?v=' %}"/>
```

How can i apply the version number to this format.

### I have tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css?v=' %}{{ v }}"/>
```

But this does not work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a little effort and hit & Trail, i found the solution.

```
{% with "APP_VERSION"|settings_value  as v %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}?v={{ v }}"/>
{% endwith %}
```